# App crash after upgrade navigation from 2.3.0 to 2.4.1

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigationview, android-navigation-graph, dynamic-feature-module

My app use dynamic-feature-module

upgrade from

```
    //Navigation Component
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_UI = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0"
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_UI_KTX = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_FRAGMENT = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0"
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_FRAGMENT_KTX = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_DYNAMIC_FEATURE = "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.0"
```

to

```
    const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_UI = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1"
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_UI_KTX = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1"
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_FRAGMENT = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1"
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_FRAGMENT_KTX = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1"
const val ANDROIDX_NAVIGATION_DYNAMIC_FEATURE = "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.4.1"
```

When I navigate to another fragment in another dynamic-feature-module it crash
with error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with ID -2046558191 is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is Destination(-2097020893) label=CartNavigationFragment class=com.myapp.CartNavigationFragment
```

How to solve this?

Comment: There's been 27 Navigation releases including one bug fix and two major releases since Navigation 2.4.1. Is there a particular reason you aren't using the latest stable version (currently, Navigation 2.6.0)?

Comment: I tried 2.4.1 because 2.5.0 required for gradle 8

Answer (score 0):

At Last I found a solution.

just upgrade to 2.6.0

because it is a bug on navigation itself

Doc [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_260_3)